# TkInter Menubar causes program to not run

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a simple text editor using TkInter. I want it to have a menu bar like other text editors, where you can save, open another file, etc.

However, whenever I try to add a menu bar to my class, the program simply starts, hangs for about half a second, then exits. I have no idea why this is happening, or how to debug it. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import functools
from tkinter import *

class mainWindow(Tk):
    def initiate(self):
        menuBarFrame = Frame(self).pack(side=TOP)
        menubar = Menu(menuBarFrame)
        menubar.add_command(label='Exit', command=quit())
        root.config(menu=menubar)
        mainloop()

win = mainWindow().initiate()
```

I tried adding `.pack()` to the line

```
menubar = Menu(menuBarFrame)
```

but it gives me the following traceback:

```
  File "XML.py", line 14, in <module>
    win = mainWindow().initiate()
  File "XML.py", line 9, in initiate
    menubar = Menu(menuBarFrame).pack()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1977, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: can't pack ".140664986043280": it's a top-level window
```

When I remove the code for the menubar, and just replace it with a simple button, the application works and starts fine. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: You seem to be missing some things. Your refer to `root` but never define it, you call `mainloop()` on its own rather than on a `tkinter` object, `win` is unnecessarily saving `None`, etc. Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `menuBarFrame` is also `None`, since you're storing the return value of the `pack()` method instead of the `Frame` object receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu needs to be a child of the root window, rather than a child of a frame. You don't need `MenuBarFrame` at all.

Also, take a look at this line:

```
menubar.add_command(label='Exit', command=quit())
```

You are instructing Tkinter to immediately call the `quit()` function, and assign the result to the `command` attribute of the menu command. I'm guessing that `quit()` actually quits rather than returning a reference to some other function. You need to change it to this:

```
menubar.add_command(label='Exit', command=quit)
```

Of course, the other glaring problem is that you don't actually define `root` anywhere.

You definitely don't want to call `pack()` on the instance of `Menu`. The correct way to attach the menu to the window is with `root.config(menu=menubar)`, like you're already doing.